# JQuery : Add Existing <option> tag in <select> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

firstly thanks in advance.
in my jsp page i have two  tag . at run time i want to remove multiple selected options tag and insert these tag into another  tag. whith following code i have done add and remove one option tag.

```
$("input[type=button]").removeAttr("disabled");
    var option =  $('#availableExpert option:selected');
    $('#availableExpert option:selected').remove();
    $('#assignedExpert').append('<option value='+option.val()+'>'+option.text()+'</option>');
```

how this is done with Multi select options tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$("input[type=button]").prop("disabled", false);
$('#availableExpert option:selected').detach().appendTo('#assignedExpert');
```